# Tkinter Spinbox Widget Setting Default Value

Tags: tkinter

I have a tkinter spinbox:

```
sb = Spinbox(frame, from_=1, to=12)
```

I would like to set the default value of spinbox to 4. How do i do this ?

i have read this thread where Bryan suggests setting

```
Tkinter.Spinbox(values=(1,2,3,4))
sb.delete(0,"end")
sb.insert(0,2)
```

But i did not get the logic behind it.

What has delete and insert to do with setting default values ?

Any further insight would be appreciated.

thanks

Comment: Just think about the `Spinbox` in terms of an `Entry`. The user can edit it in a similar way. And the `insert` part is just like Perl or PHP. If it were python, you'd need to write `sb.insert(0, '2')`... And `'end'` is the actual value of the magic constant `Tkinter.END`. Welcome to the stringly world.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`sb.delete(0,"end")` is used to remove all the text from the Spinbox, and with `sb.insert(0,2)` you insert the number 2 as the new value.

You can also set a default value with the `textvariable` option:

```
var = StringVar(root)
var.set("4")
sb = Spinbox(root, from_=1, to=12, textvariable=var)
```

Comment: I kinda have the feeling that this just works if you use `` and `` but not with the `` argument. Do you know a way to do it with the values argument? (Bryans way didn't worked either.)

Answer (score 7):

As shortcut you could use:

```
var = tk.DoubleVar(value=2)  # initial value
spinbox = tk.Spinbox(root, from_=1, to=12, textvariable=var)
```

Optional you may make the value readonly:

`spinbox = tk.Spinbox(root, from_=1, to=12, textvariable=var, state='readonly')`