# How to set the value for a spin box?

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

How do I set the value for a spin box. I know that using the set command works for scrollbars, but I can't seem to find the equivalent for spin boxes.

Comment: A Spinbox is basically an Entry with a couple of buttons tacked on, so you'd change the value just as you would with an Entry - ``widget.delete(0, "end"); widget.insert(0, "NEWVALUE")``

Comment: This question is covered by [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16500052/tkinter-spinbox-widget-setting-default-value)

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign a `Variable` to your `Spinbox`:

```
var = tkinter.DoubleVar(value=42)
# This will create a Spinbox with its default value set to 42.
box = tkinter.Spinbox(master, textvariable=var)
```

Later you can change the value of your `Spinbox` by changing the assigned variable:

```
# This will set the Spinbox to 123.
var.set(123)
```